# How do i center an image in a row

Tags: html, image

How do i center an image in a row.
My code is not working.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s10">
            <img class="center" src="house.png" alt="House"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are no problems with a text tag (e.g. `h1` or `p`)

Edit: The class `center-align` doesn't work either.

Comment: you can use `text-center` like this: `<div class="col s10 text-center">`

Comment: Thank you. It works

Comment: if you are desperate you can check http://howtocenterincss.com ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `text-center` like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col s10 text-center">
          <img class="center" src="house.png" alt="House"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works if the images CSS is `display:inline` for example. If it were display block then `.text-center` would not work. -1 for half working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for centring images.

```
.img-center {
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

> Using `.text-center` will **only** work for `display:inline` images. Most of the time your images will be `display:block`. The solution above does not account for this.

Apply to your images like so:

```css
.col {
  border:1px solid green;
}


.img-center { 
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col s10">
          <img class="img-center" src="https://placehold.it/200x100" alt="House"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```